# How can I change the color panel specific in panels array

Tags: c#, arrays, panel

I create a chess board with panels and I create for 8 queen problem for display queen and below code. I can't change color specific cell board for show queen in form.

```
        const int tileSize = 50;
        const int gridSize = 8;
        var clr1 = Color.Black;
        var clr2 = Color.White;

        // initialize the "chess board"
        _chessBoardPanels = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize];

        // double for loop to handle all rows and columns
        for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
        {
            for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
            {
                // create new Panel control which will be one 
                // chess board tile
                var newPanel = new Panel
                {
                    Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                    Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                };

                // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
                Controls.Add(newPanel);

                // add to our 2d array of panels for future use
                _chessBoardPanels[n, m] = newPanel;

                // color the backgrounds
                if (n % 2 == 0)

                    newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr1 : clr2;
                else
                    newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr2 : clr1;

            }
```

pleas help :how can i change the color panel specific and show in form ? this sample code i wirte.

```
                int[] x = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 0, 2 };
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {

                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                newPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
                                _chessBoardPanels[x[i], i] = newPanel;
                                break;
                            }

                            ...
                    }
                }
```

Comment: do you case checks for case 1 but the `i` is initialized to `0` so you are aware that arrays are `0` based in .net..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Panel[,] _chessBoardPanels = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            const int tileSize = 50;
            const int gridSize = 8;
            var clr1 = Color.Black;
            var clr2 = Color.White;

            // initialize the "chess board"
            _chessBoardPanels = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize];

            // double for loop to handle all rows and columns
            for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
            {
                for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
                {
                    // create new Panel control which will be one 
                    // chess board tile
                    var newPanel = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                        Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                    };

                    // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
                    Controls.Add(newPanel);

                    // add to our 2d array of panels for future use
                    _chessBoardPanels[n, m] = newPanel;

                    // color the backgrounds
                    if (n % 2 == 0)

                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr1 : clr2;
                    else
                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr2 : clr1;

                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                int[] x = new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 0, 2 };
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {

                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            {
                                _chessBoardPanels[x[i], i].BackColor  = Color.Red;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```